# script for a HTML document to change default printer and restore after the print job

Tags: javascript, html, vba, templates, printing

First of all i'm an inexperienced hobby programmer and for my work I sometimes do some small programming things. Most of the time after some intensive research and internet searches I find my way and solve things. But this time I'm out of solutions.

On my work we have software who prints a html template with a qr code. The problem is it always prints to the default printer and we want it to print to another printer then default. I tried so many things including registry settings in the pagesetup of internet explorer and scripts I found on the internet but it keeps printing to the default printer. Does anyone have an idea if this is possible? Setup: Windows 10x64 and our software always prints via internet explorer (ieframe.dll)